# Retrieving JSON data in PHP (having 'Undefined Property' error)

Tags: php, json, api, decode, encode

I want to get data from API but instead keep getting 'Undefined Property' PHP error.

I am trying to get 'SESSION_ID' in Datas in Data. (JSON/POST)

```
{
"Data":
{
    "Code":"00",
    "Datas":
    {
        "COM_CODE":"80001",
        "USER_ID":"USER_ID",
        "SESSION_ID":"39313231367c256562253866253939256563253838253938:0HDD9DBtZt2e"
    },
    "Message":"",
    "RedirectUrl":""
},
"Status":"200",
"Error":null 
}
```

And my PHP code to retrieve `SESSION_ID` is like this. First, sending `$data` and get the `SESSION_ID`.

```
function api_login(){


$data = array(
    "COM_CODE" => "000000",
    "USER_ID" => "USER"
    );

$ch = curl_init( "https://apifakeurl.com/Login" );
$payload = json_encode($data);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $payload );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$json = json_decode($result);

$session_id = $json->Data->Datas->SESSION_ID;
//Here is the line where I get the 'Undefined Property' error.

return $session_id;
}
```

As I am PHP beginner, I am not sure whether that one error line is the problem, or the whole structure is wrong. Please help!

Comment: `echo $result` and see if it's the same JSON as you posted. If it is exactly the same, you should not be getting an "Undefined Property" error message.

Comment: You should be checking that $result != false before using the data as it's also possible that this part can fail for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: @AmalMurali Thanks for your help. `$result` was the problem.

Comment: @NigelRen I checked the `$result` and now it is working. Thanks for taking your time! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your return from the $result is really like the json you wrote, your code is working,

i think you need to `print_r($result)` from the curl;

this code might help:

```
<?php


$json = '{
"Data":
{
    "Code":"00",
    "Datas":
    {
        "COM_CODE":"80001",
        "USER_ID":"USER_ID",
        "SESSION_ID":"39313231367c256562253866253939256563253838253938:0HDD9DBtZt2e"
    },
    "Message":"",
    "RedirectUrl":""
},
"Status":"200",
"Error":null 
}';

echo '<pre>';
$decode = json_decode($json);
print_r(json_decode($json));
$session_id = $decode->Data->Datas->SESSION_ID;
echo $session_id;
```

Comment: Yes. The problem was in the `$data` I send to retrieve `$json`. I newly learned the usage of `print_r`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: your welcome @DahnHwang , also you can use var_dump($variable); for more details

Answer (score 0):

I had luck with this syntax: 
`$session_id = $json['Data']['Datas']['SESSION_ID'];`

Didn't work without single quotes inside brackets.

Comment: The `SESSSION_ID` I wanted to get was formatted in array not in object. Thanks for taking your time anyway.